# create File object in javascript and upload it to input field

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, typescript

I have an image as a file

```
var file = new File(...);
```

and I want to "upload" it to an input field (in order to send it to the server later when submitting my form)

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenInput" name="Files[0]"/>
```

Is it possible to do something like that?

Comment: You could add the file before submitting the form using javascript

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I'm trying to do, but I don't know how. I've tried to set the value() of the input, but it takes only string so it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: maybe use a file input field which is hidden using CSS?

Comment: I've also thought about that, but again the value is some string. I also tried to use input.files and to set the input.files[0], but it is readonly, so I didn't come up with a solution that seem to work for loading the file from JavaScript. Maybe I'm missing something

Comment: The way I have done it is to send the request via ajax and when a successful response comes I reload the page.

Comment: there is no actual way to set the value of a input file from javascript. it will only affect the text but not the metadata

Comment: Unless the file can be converted to `String64` and decoded on the server back to file